# Async abstract method and derived classes in API design

Tags: .net, asynchronous, abstract-class, c#-5.0

I have an **abstract class** MyAbstractDoerClass which has an **abstract method** called DoItAsync as follow:

```
public class MyAbtractDoerClass
{
    public abstract Task DoItAsync();
}
```

It also has a couple of derived classes PainterClass and EraserClass:

```
public class PainterClass : MyAbtractDoerClass
{
    public override async Task DoItAsync();
}

public class EraserClass : MyAbtractDoerClass
{
    public override async Task DoItAsync();
}
```

Finally, there is a Factory method that returns an instance of any of these two classes. The signature is something like this:

```
public MyAbstractClass Factory(string doerType)
```

Now, my code looks like this:

```
var doer = Factory("painter");
await doer.DoItAsync();  // <--- here is the problem.
```

Given that MyAbstractClass.DoItAsync method is an abstract one, it cannot be marked as async and because of that I cannot use the await keyword in the API client. That makes my API usability seem very bad. I suspect there is something wrong in my design, some concept that I didn't fully understand but I don't know what.

What is wrong with my code?

**Update**

This is the error that I got in VS:
[image]

And this is the method's signature in the abstract class:

[image]

Comment: Since `DoItAsync()` returns a `Task`, it should be `await`able. Are you sure the method you're calling it from is marked as `async`?

Comment: @Jason, the method in the abstract class cannot be marked as async.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I've updated my question with the error message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You certainly *can* do this:

```
await doer.DoItAsync();
```

The key point of understanding is that *types* are awaitable, not *methods*. You can do `await doer.DoItAsync()` because `DoItAsync` returns a `Task`, not because `DoItAsync` is `async`. I explain this more in my [`async` intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Put another way, that code is exactly the same as:

```
Task temp = doer.DoItAsync();
await temp;
```

I have an ["`async` OOP" series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/async%20oop) on my blog; one of the posts covers [`async` in inheritance scenarios](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-1-inheritance-and-interfaces.html).

Comment: @lontivero: You say there's a "problem", but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: the problem is that the usage of the _temp_ variable doesn't look natural for me. As a developer, when I see VS say "(awaitable) XXX", it also says "Usage: await XXX" however, developers that will use my API will be forced to use a _temporary_ variable. The problem is an usability problem.

Comment: You don't need to use temp variable it is just figurative example.

Comment: Um, there's no need to use a `temp` variable. I was pointing out that `await MethodAsync()` is the same as `Task temp = MethodAsync(); await temp;`.

Comment: Here is the another great article from Stephen Toub which explain what does the async and await. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx

Comment: You just need to make the **calling** method `async`.